# Trabajar con un arraylist en diferentes clases

Tags: java

¿Saben si puedo trabajar con un solo array dentro para varias clases? Y, si esto es así, ¿cómo puedo pasar el array a otra clase?

En esta clase tengo mis métodos para leer, escribir y convertir mi colección a texto y de texto a colección, quiero guardar los datos en una sola `Arraylist`, pero no sé como puedo pasar ese array a mi clase *AgregarEmpleado*

```
package clases.archivos; 

public class ArchivoLogin{

     private final String ARCHIVO_LOGIN = "archivo.txt";
```

Este es el array que quiero pasar a mi clase *archivoLogin*

```
ArrayList<EmpleadoClase> empleadosArchivo = new ArrayList<EmpleadoClase>();


public void escribirArchivo(String nuevo){         
    try{                        
        File file = new File(ARCHIVO_LOGIN);        
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);        
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);        
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
        System.out.println("nuevo: " + nuevo);
    
        pw.write(nuevo);            
        pw.close();            
        bw.close();
        System.out.println("Escribio");
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("El archivo no se puede manipular...");
    }
}

public void leerArchivo(){        
    empleadosArchivo.clear(); 
    try{             
        FileReader fl = new FileReader(ARCHIVO_LOGIN); 
        BufferedReader bl = new BufferedReader(fl);                     

        String contenidoArchivo =""; 

        while((contenidoArchivo = bl.readLine()) != null ){                
            EmpleadoClase usuario = convertirTextoAEmpleado(contenidoArchivo);                
            empleadosArchivo.add(usuario); 
        }            
        bl.close(); 
    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("Error al cargar el archivo: "+ex.getMessage());
    }catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Error al leer o cerrar el archivo: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private EmpleadoClase convertirTextoAEmpleado(String texto){        
    String[] elementosTexto = texto.split(","); 

    EmpleadoClase usuarioLectura = new EmpleadoClase(); 
    Direccion direccion = new Direccion(); 
    Usuario usuario =  new Usuario(); 

    usuarioLectura.setIdentificador(elementosTexto[0]);
    usuarioLectura.setNombre(elementosTexto[1]);
    usuarioLectura.setFechaNacimiento(elementosTexto[2]);
    usuarioLectura.setGenero(elementosTexto[3]);
    usuarioLectura.setSalario(elementosTexto[4]);
    direccion.setCalle(elementosTexto[5]);    
    direccion.setColonia(elementosTexto[6]);  
    direccion.setNumero(elementosTexto[7]);  
    usuario.setUsuarioB(elementosTexto[8]);
    usuario.setContrasena(elementosTexto[9]);

    return usuarioLectura; 
}

public String conviertirColeccionATexto(){
    String datos = "";
    for(int i=0; i < empleadosArchivo.size(); i++){
        EmpleadoClase usuarioCopia = empleadosArchivo.get(i);          
        datos += usuarioCopia.getIdentidicador()+","+usuarioCopia.getNombre()+","+usuarioCopia.getFechaNacimiento()+","+usuarioCopia.getGenero()+","+usuarioCopia.getSalario()+","+usuarioCopia.getDireccion()+","+usuarioCopia.getUsuario(); 
        if(i != empleadosArchivo.size()-1){
            datos += "\n";                
        }            
    }
    return datos;
}



}
```

En esta clase, es donde se va a obtener toda la información que se va a enviar al `ArrayList` y desde aquí quiero guardar esa información para después poder guardar esa información en la colección y en el archivo
`package ventanas.ventanasEmpleado;`.

Mi problema está aquí, ya que no sé cómo puedo mover mi arraylist a otra clase.

```
public class AgregarEmpleado extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener{

JLabel lbTitulo; 
JLabel lbIdentificador; 
JTextField tfIdentificador; 
JLabel lbNombre; 
JTextField tfNombre;     
JLabel lbTituloDireccion; 
JLabel lbCalle; 
JTextField tfCalle; 
JLabel lbNumero; 
JTextField tfNumero; 
JLabel lbColonia; 
JTextField tfColonia; 
JLabel lbFechaNacimiento; 
JTextField tfFechaNacimiento; 
JLabel lbGenero;      
JComboBox cbGenero; 
JLabel lbSalario; 
JTextField tfSalario;
JLabel lbTituloUsuario; 
JTextField tfTituloUsuario; 
JLabel lbUsuario; 
JTextField tfUsuario; 
JLabel lbContrasena; 
JTextField tfContrasena; 
JButton btGuardar; 
JButton btRegresar;     


String[] generos; //info del comboBox
ArrayList<EmpleadoClase> empleadosColeccion = new ArrayList<EmpleadoClase>();     

public AgregarEmpleado(){
    this.setTitle("Agregar Empleado"); 
    this.setSize(700, 500); 
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setLayout(null);                
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);        
    inicializarComponentes(); 
}

public void inicializarComponentes(){

    lbTitulo = new JLabel("Agregar Empleado"); 
    lbTitulo.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lbTitulo.setFont(new Font("Time New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));                         
    lbTitulo.setBounds(200, 15, 300, 25);
    this.add(lbTitulo); 

    //fila 1
    lbIdentificador = new JLabel("Idenficador"); 
    lbIdentificador.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);        
    lbIdentificador.setBounds(75, 60, 100, 25);                     
    this.add(lbIdentificador);

    tfIdentificador = new JTextField(); 
    tfIdentificador.setBounds(75, 90, 100, 25); 
    this.add(tfIdentificador); 

    lbNombre = new JLabel("Nombre"); 
    lbNombre.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);        
    lbNombre.setBounds(205, 60, 250, 25);                
    this.add(lbNombre); 

    tfNombre = new JTextField(); 
    tfNombre.setBounds(205, 90, 250, 25); 
    this.add(tfNombre); 

    lbFechaNacimiento = new JLabel("Fecha de Nacimiento"); 
    lbFechaNacimiento.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);        
    lbFechaNacimiento.setBounds(475, 60, 150, 25);         
    this.add(lbFechaNacimiento); 

    tfFechaNacimiento = new JTextField(); 
    tfFechaNacimiento.setBounds(475, 90, 150, 25); 
    this.add(tfFechaNacimiento); 

    //fila 2
    lbGenero = new JLabel("Genero");    
    lbGenero.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);         
    lbGenero.setBounds(150, 125, 150, 25);                      
    this.add(lbGenero); 
             
    cargarDatosArreglo(); 
    cbGenero = new JComboBox<String>(generos);
    cbGenero.setBounds(150, 155, 150, 25);
    cbGenero.addItemListener(this);
    this.add(cbGenero);

    lbSalario = new JLabel("Salario"); 
    lbSalario.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);        
    lbSalario.setBounds(400, 125, 150, 25);                      
    this.add(lbSalario); 

    tfSalario = new JTextField(); 
    tfSalario.setBounds(400, 155, 150, 25);
    this.add(tfSalario);

    //fila3        
    lbCalle = new JLabel("Calle");
    lbCalle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);        
    lbCalle.setBounds(75, 190, 100, 25);
    this.add(lbCalle); 

    tfCalle = new JTextField(); 
    tfCalle.setBounds(75, 220, 100, 25);
    this.add(tfCalle); 

    lbColonia = new JLabel("Colonia"); 
    lbColonia.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);        
    lbColonia.setBounds(205, 190, 250, 25);                      
    this.add(lbColonia); 

    tfColonia = new JTextField(); 
    tfColonia.setBounds(205, 220, 250, 25);
    this.add(tfColonia); 

    lbNumero = new JLabel("Numero del Hogar"); 
    lbNumero.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);        
    lbNumero.setBounds(475, 190, 150, 25);                      
    this.add(lbNumero); 

    tfNumero = new JTextField(); 
    tfNumero.setBounds(475, 220, 150, 25);
    this.add(tfNumero); 

    //fila 4    
    lbUsuario = new JLabel("Usuario"); 
    lbUsuario.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); 
    lbUsuario.setBounds(150, 255, 150, 25 );
    this.add(lbUsuario); 

    tfUsuario = new JTextField(); 
    tfUsuario.setBounds(150, 285, 150, 25);
    this.add(tfUsuario); 

    lbContrasena = new JLabel("Contraseña");
    lbContrasena.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); 
    lbContrasena.setBounds(400, 255, 150, 25);
    this.add(lbContrasena); 

    tfContrasena = new JTextField(); 
    tfContrasena.setBounds(400, 285, 150, 25);
    this.add(tfContrasena);

    //botones       
    btRegresar = new JButton("Regresar"); 
    btRegresar.setBounds(175, 355, 100, 25);
    btRegresar.addActionListener(this);
    this.add(btRegresar);

    btGuardar = new JButton("Guardar");        
    btGuardar.setBounds(425, 355, 100, 25);
    btGuardar.addActionListener(this);
    this.add(btGuardar); 

}    

private void cargarDatosArreglo(){
    generos = new String[]{
        "--------------",
        "Masculino",
        "Femenino"
    };
}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){                
    int posicion = cbGenero.getSelectedIndex();
    
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){        
    if(ae.getSource().equals(btGuardar)){  
        System.out.println("ETREO AL BOTON");          
        guardarInformacionEmpleado();
        vaciarCuadros();                   
    }else if(ae.getSource().equals(btRegresar)){
        Empleado empleado = new Empleado(); 
        this.dispose();
    }
}

private void vaciarCuadros(){
    System.out.println("VACIAR CUADROS");
    guardarInformacionEmpleado();

    tfIdentificador.setText("");
    tfNombre.setText("");
    tfFechaNacimiento.setText("");
    cbGenero.setSelectedIndex(0);
    tfSalario.setText("");
    tfCalle.setText("");
    tfColonia.setText("");
    tfNumero.setText("");
    tfUsuario.setText("");
    tfContrasena.setText("");

}


private void guardarInformacionEmpleado(){
    System.out.println("GUARDAR INFORMACIÓN");
    String id = tfIdentificador.getText(); 
    String name = tfNombre.getText();
    String date = tfFechaNacimiento.getText(); 
    int posicio = cbGenero.getSelectedIndex(); 
    String gene = generos[posicio];
    String sal = tfSalario.getText();
    String calle = tfCalle.getText();
    String col = tfColonia.getText();
    String num = tfNumero.getText();
    String usu = tfUsuario.getText(); 
    String password = tfContrasena.getText();        

   informacionAEmpleado(id, name, date, gene, sal, calle, col, num, usu, password);
}     

private void informacionAEmpleado(String id, String name, String date, String gene, String sal, String calle, String col, String num, String usu, String password){        

    System.out.println("Información empleado");
    ArchivoLogin archivo = new ArchivoLogin();                 

    System.out.println("SE guarda información del objetp");
    Direccion direccion = new Direccion();
    direccion.setCalle(calle);
    direccion.setColonia(col);
    direccion.setNumero(num);        
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario(); 
    usuario.setUsuarioB(usu);
    usuario.setContrasena(password);
    System.out.println("SE termina información del objetp");

    System.out.println("lee información");

    archivo.leerArchivo();
    EmpleadoClase empleado = new EmpleadoClase(id, name, date, gene, sal, direccion, usuario); 
    System.out.println(empleado);

    System.out.println("agrega información");        
    empleadosColeccion.add(empleado);
    System.out.println("comvierte infromación");
    String datos = archivo.conviertirColeccionATexto(); 
    System.out.println("escribe");
    archivo.escribirArchivo(datos);

    
}    


}
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta revisando la edición de lo que es código y lo que no. Y dónde acaban y empiezan las definiciones de clases, para que todo el mundo lo entienda mejor

Answer (score 1):

Si tenes el arraylist de tipo `EmpleadoClase` en la clase `ArchivoLogin` y quieres hacer uso de ello en otras clase.

Debes crear un constructor de la clase ArchivoLogin e inicializar el ArrayList

```
private ArrayList<EmpleadoClase>empleadosArchivo;


public ArchivoLogin(){
   
   this.empleadosArchivo=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

en la clase ArchivoLogin debes crear un metodo get que te devueva ese ArrayList

```
public ArrayList<EmpleadoClase> obtenerArray(){
   return empleadosArchivo;
}
```

debes instanciar un objeto de la clase ArchivoLogin en las otras clases y hacer uso del metodo get para poder hacer uso del ArrayList

```
public class nombreDeOtraClase{
ArchivoLogin instancia=new ArchivoLogin();
ArrayList<EmpleadoClase>arraylistObtenido=instancia.obtenerArray();
}
```

Comment: Y si quiero regresar ese array a la clase donde esta implementado, deberia de hacerle  un setter al array?

Comment: El Array ya está en esa clase si quieres modificarlo desde otra clase ,un método setter es lo ideal